# Difference between multiple dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, difference

I am working in a database with multiple orders of multiple suppliers. Now I would like to know the difference in days between order 1 and order 2, order 2 and order 3, order 3 and order 4 and so on.. For each supplier on its own. I need this to generate the Standard Deviation for each supplier based on their days between orders.

Hopefully someone can help..

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected results, as well as your current attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is `lag()` with aggregation:

```
select supplier,
       stddev(orderdate - prev_orderdate) as std_orderdate
from (select t.*,
             lag(orderdate) over (partition by supplier order by orderdate) as prev_orderdate
      from t
     ) t
group by supplier;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically use window function `lag()` and date arithmetics.

Assuming the following data structure for table `orders`:

```
order_id int primary key
supplier_id int
order_date date
```

You would go:

```
select 
    i.*,
    order_date 
        - lag(order_date) over(partition by supplier_id order by order_date) date_diff
from orders o
```

Which gives you, for each order, the difference in days from the previous order of the same supplier (or `null` if this is the first order of the supplier).

You can then compute the standard deviation with aggregation:

```
select supplier_id, stddev(date_diff) 
from (
    select 
        o.*,
        order_date 
            - lag(order_date) over(partition by supplier_id order by order_date) date_diff
    from orders o
) x
group by supplier_id
```